# Deceptive site ahead - WordPress Backend Edit Post/Page

Tags: google-search-console, wordpress, google-chrome

[image: View Error Screen]
[image: View Security Issues Google Search Console]
[image: View Manual Actions Google Search Console]

Error Message (While Editing Page / Adding Page in WordPress using Google Chrome - Only happens for Chrome Users):

"Deceptive site ahead

Attackers on 24-tsb.net may trick you into doing something dangerous like installing software or revealing your personal information (for example, passwords, phone numbers, or credit cards). Learn more"

I've scanned my website using WordFence, and seek confirmation with my hosting provider which 100% my website was clean. High chances that it's fault detection reported by google. However, inside my google search console's Security & Manual Actions both were "No issues detected".

I've tried to resolve it by reporting this matter to google multiples time and it's been 2 weeks.

Comment: It also happens for Firefox users.  Since it is a wordpress site, you likely have some malware injected via a vulnerable plugin.

Comment: I mentioned above which I've scanned plugin & my hosting provider was scanned at server end. There are no malware detected.

Comment: 24-tsb-net, if you persevere, gives `24-tsb.net’s DNS address could not be found`.  Maybe you need to fix that perhaps !!!!

Comment: @HoongYawChan Just because it has been scanned doesn't mean there is no malware.  Scanners only find malware or a virus they know exists, what if you are infected with something new?

Comment: I think that, since that the domain does not exist, this question is void and should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes IP addresses and domains from previous website owners can carry over this warning, sometimes it takes a while to clear up.
If you've owned the website for a while, you should check your Search Console email address as Google would have told you about the malicious file/page.

Based on the fact that as of posting this answer, the domain name no longer exists, I am assuming that you bought the domain recently and the former part of my answer is a reasonable deduction.